# mysql update. count, rows where column is null and a columns is the same

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update

I want to update all rows in a table with a count of rows that have the same value with a where clause.

> SQL

```
//This gives me the rows I want to update    
SELECT file1 FROM database.TableName where file2 is null
//From there I want to count all the rows that are the same
SELECT Count(*) FROM database.TableName where file1 = resulted value
//And then I want to update the row
```

> My current query looks like this

```
UPDATE database.TableName AS A 
SET refCount = (SELECT Count(*) 
FROM database.TableName AS B 
WHERE A.file1 = B.file1 AND A.file2 is null)
```

> TableName

```
|ID | file1     |   file2   | refCount |
| 1 | file.txt  |           |    1     |
| 2 | file.txt  |           |    1     |
| 3 |           | file2.txt |    1     |
| 4 | file3.txt |           |    1     |
```

> TableName (Expected Results)

```
|ID | file1     |   file2   | refCount |
| 1 | file.txt  |           |    2     |
| 2 | file.txt  |           |    2     |
| 3 |           | file2.txt |    1     |
| 4 | file3.txt |           |    1     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are missing the where clause for your update statement.

Try this...

```
UPDATE database.TableName AS A 
SET refCount = 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM database.TableName AS B WHERE A.file1 = B.file1 AND A.file2 is null)
where A.file1 = B.file1
```